# How to convert Athena timestamp to string

Tags: timestamp, amazon-athena

I am using following code:

```
select date_col::TEXT from table1;
```

Error:

```
identifiers must not contain ':' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 0445a8ab-7bbc-4db2-bb6d-4d8b48bebd1f; proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try `select cast(date_col as varchar) from table1;`